# How to bring data with a search box with typing letters consecutively in Python-Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, search-box

I have created an entry box with tkinter in a page. What I want to do is to  convert it into a search box. Whenever I type a letter, I want it to bring me the data that includes these letters from my database. For example when I type "A", I want it bring all names that start with 'A'. And then I typed "L". I want it to bring me all names start with "AL". and so on. Basically each time I add a letter, I want it to update the search and bring me the data according to it. Just like google search box. Can anyone tell me what this event called? Or give a basic code example. Thanks!

Comment: You've told us what you want but haven't explained why you're having a problem implementing it. There are many examples on the internet of doing things when you press a key in a Tkinter widget. There are also plenty of examples of doing database searches. Please try to be more specific about what problem you're having.

Comment: I don't have any idea what the event is called. Im just asking for a basic code example to make the search box work the way i want. At least the name of the event..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be a bit more specific with your details so that people can help you better. What is the searchbox retrieving the data from? A database or a list maybe? You could post some code as well which would help everyone understand your predicament better. Hope this article on searchboxes helps you get started. Good luck!

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_entry.htm

This one below talks about dynamic searchboxes:

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/22nhwe/dynamic_search_barfilter_with_tkinter/